# SQL Query to replace and select all content between specific DIVs

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to run a sql query to remove some spam that was added to a website. In MySQL via phpmyadmin I want to run a SQL query to replace all content within a div and the div elements themselves.

Luckily they are all in divs with display none and look like this

```
<div style="display:none"> spam text and links</div>
```

So I want to replace it with nothing and have run update query but no link and text is the same so cannot run a few there are thousands so have to try run query that removes the div element and everything inbetween.

Any help will be massively appreciated thank you!

Comment: You can use regular expressions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: I would not do this in MySQL, I would fetch the html code into some DOM object record by record and do this removal there. In MySQL you can only use various string functions and regular expressions to locate the necessary data, which is difficult and error prone.

Comment: thanks but  have to do it in mysql it's a wordpress cms

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this. using Replace

Replace left div and right div with blank to extract content then replace the div content from the original text

```
set @str = '<div style="display:none"> spam text and links</div>';
set @open= '<div style="display:none">';
set @close = '</div>';

select  replace(@str,replace(replace(@str,@open,''),@close,''),'');
```